# How to fix encoding: Itâ€™s

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a string from the woot.com API () such as

```
addslashes(html_entity_decode(mb_convert_encoding($woot->teaser, "UTF-8")))
```

The problem is that it still turns out like `That not-too-distant future? Itâ€™s been over twenty years.`

I can't seem to fix the encoding issue... any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

**Have a look at this page**

[Unicode-friendly PHP and MySQL](http://malevolent.com/weblog/archive/2007/03/12/unicode-utf8-php-mysql/)

On this page you will find an easy and clear explaination of UTF-8 encoding and how to apply this in your websites along with some practical examples.

You will also need to make sure that your files are saved using UTF-8 encoding (without BOM).

Comment: Thanks, good guide!  I'll see if some of this does the trick.... it's a shame PHP doesn't have better UTF-8 support

Comment: Unfortunately it's not fixing the encoding issue